# Как получить значение числа?

Tags: javascript

Как получить значение из числа?

Например от **0** до **49** значение будет равно **1**, от **50** до **149** равно **2** и так далее...

Например есть переменная

> var d = 30;

согласно той таблицы мне нужно получить **1**.

То есть от **0** до **49** я всегда должен получать в переменную 1 (например переменную `var x ='';`)

Ну и так везде от **50** до **149** число **2**, от **150** до **349** число **3**

```
app.Data = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 49],
    [2, 50, 149],
    [3, 150, 349],
    [4, 350, 849],
    [5, 850, 1849],
    [6, 1850, 3849],
    [7, 3850, 5849],
    [8, 5850, 9849],
    [9, 9850, 15849],
    [10, 15850, 23849]
];
```

Comment: Форматировал вопрос и все ровно не понял о каком значении идет речь?

Comment: @Air Например есть переменная var d = 30; согласно той таблицы мне нужно получить 1. то есть от 0 до 49 я всегда должен получать в переменную 1 (например переменную var x ='';) ну и так везде т 50 до 149 число 2, от 150 до 349 число 3

Comment: @Air Проще говоря какой строке массива будет равен app.Dtata.length если в переменной d будет одно из чисел

Comment: Переделайте массив свой `app.Data` в массив массивов, типа [[0,0],[0,49],[50,149]] и так далее, получается у вас ключи массива будут 0,1,2,3... А потом проверяете входит ли ваше входное значение в диапазон одного из массивов и вытаскиваете его ключ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, например, обойти Ваш массив массивов с помощью reduce, найти массив, в диапазон которого попадает искомое число, и вернуть его первый элемент:

```js
const arr = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 49],
    [2, 50, 149],
    [3, 150, 349],
    [4, 350, 849],
    [5, 850, 1849],
    [6, 1850, 3849],
    [7, 3850, 5849],
    [8, 5850, 9849],
    [9, 9850, 15849],
    [10, 15850, 23849]
];

const getNum = function(num) {
  let result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if(num >= item[1] && num <= item[2] ) {
      return acc = item[0];
    }
    return acc;
  }, 0)
  return result;
}
console.log(getNum(30))
console.log(getNum(500))
console.log(getNum(1500))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо то что надо.

Comment: Что это за ужасный цикл там внутри?

Comment: @Igor, пардоньте, это рудимент другого решения :) исправил

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = {
  Data: [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 49],
    [2, 50, 149],
    [3, 150, 349],
    [4, 350, 849],
    [5, 850, 1849],
    [6, 1850, 3849],
    [7, 3850, 5849],
    [8, 5850, 9849],
    [9, 9850, 15849],
    [10, 15850, 23849]
  ]
};
function mapValue(map, value) {
  if (map.length && (value < map[0][1] || value > map[map.length - 1][2]))
    return NaN; 
  for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    if (value >= map[i][1] && value <= map[i][2]) {
      return map[i][0];
    }
  }
  return NaN;
}
console.log(mapValue(app.Data, 2222));
console.log(mapValue(app.Data, 55555));
console.log(mapValue(app.Data, -5555));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let app = {};
app.Data = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 49],
    [2, 50, 149],
    [3, 150, 349],
    [4, 350, 849],
    [5, 850, 1849],
    [6, 1850, 3849],
    [7, 3850, 5849],
    [8, 5850, 9849],
    [9, 9850, 15849],
    [10, 15850, 23849]
  ];

function findInterval(data, value) {
  let interval = data.find(int => int[1] <= value && int[2] >= value);
  return interval ? interval[0] : NaN;
}
console.log(findInterval(app.Data, 0));
console.log(findInterval(app.Data, 50));
console.log(findInterval(app.Data, 1000));
console.log(findInterval(app.Data, 100000));
```